# PayloadFactory - Enrich with Response

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I make a callout that response is like this:

```
<ns:return>
    <ax2446:contract>
        <ax2446:array>variable1</ax2446:array>
        <ax2446:array>value1</ax2446:array>
    </ax2446:contract>
    <ax2446:contract>
        <ax2446:array>variable2</ax2446:array>
        <ax2446:array>value2</ax2446:array>
    </ax2446:contract>
    <ax2446:contract>
        <ax2446:array>variable3</ax2446:array>
        <ax2446:array>value3</ax2446:array>
    </ax2446:contract>
    <ax2446:documents>
        <ax2446:array>attachement1</ax2446:array>
        <ax2446:array>D:\AUTO\filename-1.txt</ax2446:array>
    </ax2446:documents>
    <ax2446:documents>
        <ax2446:array>attachment2</ax2446:array>
        <ax2446:array>D:\AUTO\filename-2.txt</ax2446:array>
    </ax2446:documents>
    <ax2446:process>TEST_PROCESS</ax2446:modulo>
</ns:return>
```

i want to create a new payload with contracts values (the number can change)

```
   <p:instantiateProcess xmlns:p="http://carbon.sample">
      <xs:process xmlns:xs="http://carbon.sample">TEST_PROCESS</xs:process>
      <ns:contract xmlns:ns="http://carbon.sample">
         <xs:array xmlns:xs="http://carbon.sample">variable1</xs:array>
         <xs:array xmlns:xs="http://carbon.sample">value1</xs:array>
      </ns:contract>
      <ns:contract xmlns:ns="http://carbon.sample">
         <xs:array xmlns:xs="http://carbon.sample">variable2</xs:array>
         <xs:array xmlns:xs="http://carbon.sample">value2</xs:array>
      </ns:contract>
      <ns:contract xmlns:ns="http://carbon.sample">
         <xs:array xmlns:xs="http://carbon.sample">variable3</xs:array>
         <xs:array xmlns:xs="http://carbon.sample">value3</xs:array>
      </ns:contract>
   </p:instantiateProcess>´
```

i get all the contract by:

```
<property
        expression="//ns:return/ax2431:contract"
        name="contract" scope="default" type="STRING"
        xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.sample/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://carbon.sample"/>
```

I try with payloadfactory, by i dont know how to enrinch (if it is correct to use this mediator) the message to make a call to a new web service. or if i have to make the payload with an iterator...

can anybody help me? thanks

Comment: you can use the xslt mediator and create a xsl transformation.

Comment: i see in documentation "The XSLT Mediator applies a specified XSLT transformation to a selected element of the current message payload"

but in my case i do not transform the payload, y muste create a new one (with payload factory) and get all the contract elements from the response of the fisrt webservice callout and put it on the new payload. it is clear my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a few options:

1. Use a Payload factory
2. Use XSLT
3. Use Script meditator

I suspect all 3 could get the result you are after. It is a question of which you feel most comfortable with. Personally, I would head down the Script mediator route, mapping between two XML payloads, here is an example: http://nimbleapi.com/2016/05/javascript-mapping-between-xml-payloads/

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the *contract* list you can use iterate mediator to iterate the list and inside the iterator you can add *payloadFactory mediator* to create payload, then, same time you can send the modified payload to a new web service.

Please find the following links which explain in detail how you use iterate mediator.

http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-use-iterator-mediator-to-iterate.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to XSLT or Script meditators, ForEach mediator is also an option.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ForEach+Mediator